# Image cropper with compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, overlay, crop

I'm trying to implement simple image cropper with compose.
The overlay can be resized and drag over the image.
The problem is, it can be dragged out of the image and out of screen too.
How to set limits for the overlay to move and resized over the image only?

The updated code

```
@Composable
fun ImageCrooper() {
  var size by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
  
  var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
  var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
  
  var height by remember { mutableStateOf(140f) }
  var width by remember { mutableStateOf(140f) }
  BoxWithConstraints(
    Modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .height(240.dp)
      .onSizeChanged {
        size = it.toSize()
      }
  ) {
    Image(
      modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
      contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
      painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = "https://i.picsum.photos/id/216/200/200.jpg?hmac=7Weas8POu49YrmUyJ6tWdqVMx-hw6lryzl8HnHZBzjc"
      ),
      contentDescription = "A Content description",
    )
    BoxWithConstraints(
      modifier = Modifier
        .offset {
          IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt())
        }
        .height(height.dp)
        .width(width.dp)
    ) {
      //      move the overlay
      Box(
        Modifier
          .background(Color.Black.copy(0.6f))
          .fillMaxSize()
          .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
              change.consumeAllChanges()
              offsetY = (offsetY + dragAmount.y).coerceIn(0f, 230f)
              offsetX = (offsetX + dragAmount.x).coerceIn(0f, size.width)
            }
          }
      )
      //      resize the overlay
      
      Box(
        Modifier
          .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
          .background(Color.White)
          .height(20.dp)
          .width(20.dp)
          .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
              change.consumeAllChanges()
              width = (width + dragAmount.x).coerceIn(140f, size.width - width)
              height = (height + dragAmount.y).coerceIn(140f, size.height - height)
        
            }
          }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit offset variables inside your Composable dimension bounds using `coerceIn` functions. You can get size of your Composable using

```
var size by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
Modifier.onSizeChanged {
    size = it.toSize()
}

offsetY = (offsetY + dragAmount.y).coerceIn(0f, size.height)
offsetX = (offsetX + dragAmount.x).coerceIn(0f, size.width)
```

Updated your code to resize or move, i'm currently [building one](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Image-Cropper), you can use it as reference. There are few things to consider

1- You need two rectangles, one for drawing overlay another for clipping rectangle. Zoom, pan and resize is applied only to crop rectangle while draw rectangle is panned and resized.

2- You need to check touch positions with change parameter in drag because each touch position has different action. While moving from left corners to right reduce width of your rectangle moving from right corners to right grow it.

3- You need to calculate touch position to edge of corners. This is for not jumping edge of your rectangle to user's touch position.

These are basics i remember. There are many complexities when zoom, pan and limiting pan inside bounds and animating back to valid bounds are involved.

And please write x coordinate before y, width before height all the time to not put wrong values in wrong variables. Currently it's prone to mistakes.

```
@Composable
fun ImageCroper() {


    BoxWithConstraints {


        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

        val minSize = 300f
        var width by remember { mutableStateOf(minSize) }
        var height by remember { mutableStateOf(minSize) }

        val widthInDp:Dp
        val heightInDp:Dp

        with(LocalDensity.current){
            widthInDp = width.toDp()
            heightInDp = height.toDp()
        }


        val imageWidth = constraints.maxWidth
        val imageHeight =  constraints.maxHeight

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                model = "https://i.picsum.photos/id/216/200/200.jpg?hmac=7Weas8POu49YrmUyJ6tWdqVMx-hw6lryzl8HnHZBzjc"
            ),
            contentDescription = "A Content description",
        )
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt())
                }
                .size(widthInDp, heightInDp)
        ) {
            //      move the overlay
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .background(Color.Black.copy(0.6f))
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                            offsetX = (offsetX + dragAmount.x).coerceIn(
                                0f,
                                (imageWidth- width).coerceAtLeast(0f)
                            )
                            offsetY = (offsetY + dragAmount.y).coerceIn(
                                0f,
                                (imageHeight- height).coerceAtLeast(0f)
                            )
                        }
                    }
            )
            //      resize the overlay

            Box(
                Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .height(20.dp)
                    .width(20.dp)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                            width = (width + dragAmount.x).coerceIn(
                                minSize,
                                (imageWidth -offsetX).coerceAtLeast(minSize)
                            )
                            height = (height + dragAmount.y).coerceIn(
                                minSize,
                                (imageHeight -offsetY).coerceAtLeast(minSize)                            )

                        }
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, now the overlay is inside the image bounds. but when increasing the overlay height its getting out of the image and can be dragged out of the image too.

Comment: subtract rectangle or overlay's current size from upper bound size.width -rect.width and for the height

Comment: It still get out of view, I've update my question with the new code

Comment: Thanks, now its working as excepted, the only problem now, that when using Bitmap.createBitmap to crop and save, the positions are wrong and the output is other area of the image, any idea why? Bitmap.createBitmap( thebitmap, offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt() , width.roundToInt(), height.roundToInt() )

Comment: Of course it will have wrong values. You have the drawing rect, in answer that's why i wrote you need another rect for crop. That rect needs to interpolate or scale from drawing size to bitmap size. Let's say you have 1000x1000px area(your Composable) and 2000x2000px Bitmap. When your rect is first quarter of drawing area which is Rect(0,0,500,500) but this is for drawing, it's first quarter. You should scale this to match Bitmap bounds which should be Rect(0,0,1000,1000)

Comment: You should check the link i provided. I'm, today, working on it. It has everything you need to do basic crop

Comment: Ok, I'll use your library,  thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246693/discussion-between-thracian-and-chkml).

Comment: For now you can only use it reference to understand basics of cropping but it would help you understand the items i mentioned above. If my answer helped please accept this answer